# Update a Record in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm having the following query while updating a particular record.

I've a user Column Family CF as follow:-

```
class User(Model):
    user_id = UUID(default=uuid.uuid4,primary_key= True)
    date = DateTime(primary_key=True,default=datetime.now())
    model = Text()
    gender = Text()
    imei = Text()
```

Now I want to filter users by `gender, model and imei`. So I made 3 models as follow. Note I could have defined `model, gender and imei` as **secondary indexes**, but secondary indexing has exponentially lower performance than normal querying, as there's nothing clever about it to back performance. Anything above a thousand records will seriously impair performance, hence I made 3 separate CF.

```
class UserByGender(Model):
    gender = Text(primary_key=True)
    date = DateTime(primary_key=True,default=datetime.now())
    user_id = UUID(index=True)


class UserByModel(Model):
    model = Text(primary_key=True)
    date = DateTime(primary_key=True,default=datetime.now())
    user_id = UUID(index=True)


class UserByImei(Model):
    imei1 = Text(primary_key=True)
    date = DateTime(primary_key=True,default=datetime.now())
    user_id = UUID(index=True)
```

I'm able to query and filter the total users by `gender, model and imei`. But the problem arises when I need to either **update/delete** a particular record.

While updating imei of a particular user, given the user_id,I do the following

I run the following query.

```
imei_user_list = UserByImei.objects.get(user_id = 'some_user_id').update(model='updated value')  
#Note: over here I'm again filtering by a secondary index. Is it worth?
```

I know the PK cannot be updated. Hence I thought of a solution, that I'll delete it first and then re-write the record, but deletes in cassandra rely on Tombstones to support the eventual consistency model.

How do I perform update operations on such model? Or how can I re-design my CF such that I'm able to update a record AND read the records(based on my different filters) as well ?